# Weird result with string.split() and Regular Expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to split this string:

```
values = "43/320x240/99/0/0,34/320x240/9/0/115,18/320x240/9/0/115,5/320x240/7/0/0"
```

And get only the first number for each "group". Instead of splitting by , and / I'm trying to do it with only one Regular Expression. But when I try this:

```
values.split(/\/(\d|x|\/)+,?/g)
```

I get this:

```
["43", "0", "34", "5", "18", "5", "5", "0"]
```

Instead of:

```
["43", "34", "18", "5"]
```

Why is there an invalid number between each number that I want? It seems that Rails is getting all numbers before and after the comma. I tried with this other RegExp: (/[\d|x]+){4},? and got a similar result.

Is there something wrong that I can't see? Do you know a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that split returns the capture groups as well.  Try using non-capturing parentheses, or better yet, a character class:

```
values.split(/\/[\dx\/]+,?/g)
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. According to http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split, "If _pattern_ contains groups, the respective matches will be returned in the array as well."

Comment: I've read on the docs about groups, but I didn't realize it was the problem in this case. It's working perfectly now, thank you!! :D